# How can I build a partition wall in room without damaging marble floor

Tags: walls, partition

I have large room size in my home, 12'x 22'. Now I want to rent it and therefore, want to divide the room in two with a partition wall. 
Is there any way to build a permanent partition wall on marble flooring without cutting or damaging it?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to damage the floor, the best way around this is to attach your bottom plate, usually a 2x4, to the floor with construction adhesive. Then add your studs and top plate. You could also just assemble all the framing on the floor and then raise the walls, using construction adhesive for the bottom plates, walls and ceiling if desired. The wall would be permanent but could be removed without damaging the floor

Comment: I'd use clear silicone. It's rock solid in applications like that and not nearly as frustrating to clean up later.

Comment: Didn't think about the cleanup....

Answer (score 1):

I would look at securing the stud work to the floor with a double sided sticky tape and then sealing each side with a bead of silicone.

That way any liquid split could not "get across" and it should be easy enough to remove later.